# Create new Guid before Commit

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am using ASP.net MVC using C# and I am currently trying to create a few create pages.  In my controller I know I need to create a new GUID (since I use them in my database), however it is crashing on the commit.  What am I doing wrong?  This is my first project in MVC and C#.

Here is my code:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult EditRole(Role role)
    {
        role.RoleID = System.Guid.NewGuid();
        roles.Update(role);
        roles.Commit();

        return RedirectToAction("RoleList");
    }
```

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: Why do you assign a new ID to the role parameter? Normally it has an ID already, since you want to update an entity that is already in your storage, than the Update method will look up for your role entity *based on the id*, and set the properties. 
If you generate a new ID for the parameter the lookup inside the Update method won't find anything.

Comment: Wow I am an idiot.  I meant to put that on the Create page. thank you for pointing that out. lol

Answer (score 1):

Why do you assign a new ID to the role parameter? Normally it has an ID already, since you want to update an entity that is already in your storage, than the Update method will look up for your role entity based on the id, and set the properties. If you generate a new ID for the parameter the lookup inside the Update method won't find anything